# react-router 6 useSearchParams not working

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I want to get the URL search params and their values using react-router 6, the approach provided in the documentation is as follows :

```
import * as React from "react";
import { useSearchParams } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  let [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();

  function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // The serialize function here would be responsible for
    // creating an object of { key: value } pairs from the
    // fields in the form that make up the query.
    let params = serializeFormQuery(event.target);
    setSearchParams(params);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>{/* ... */}</form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and this is the link https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-search-params.
I'm trying to do the same thing here but I don't understand where serializeFormQuery() is supposed to come from. I tried this code and it didn't work:

```
import {useSearchParams} from "react-router-dom";

myFunction() {

let [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();
 const logSearchParams = () => {
    let params = serializeFormQuery(searchParams);
    console.log(params);
  };
logSearchParams()
}
```

Is serializeFormQuery just a function example? meaning I should create it or am I missing something? because it's undefined.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: _"Is serializeFormQuery just a function example? meaning I should create it"_ -- yes, this function an example. The point that the code (and comment) is trying to get across, is that `setSearchParams` will take any _"object of { key: value } pairs"_

Comment: What exactly is the issue? What isn't working as expected?

Comment: Thank you @George.
It's fixed @DrewReese . I had to do ```searchParams.get("foo")```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- It would be used with `forms` which forms objects of field values used inside the form as mentioned in the docs as well, if you are not using a form then it is not required tmk ..

you might just want to read from returned values of the hook as

```
import {useSearchParams} from "react-router-dom";
function SampleApp = () => {
  let [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();
  const logSearchParams = () => {
    console.log(searchParams.get("samplekey"));  // url is assumed as https://.....com?samplekey="dummy"
  };
  logSearchParams();
 
  .....
}
```

Comment: I just tried that and it didn't work. That returned a big object. The built-in module function I think.
see [link](https://ibb.co/WsGfh3L) @KcH

Comment: my bad ... yes, you have to get from the key of the param ... (edited)

Comment: Sorry but it's not working. keys length is 0. Would you mind to elaborate? @KcH

Comment: Usually searchParams would return a URLSearchParams  object which by itself is not so useful for us .. [You can read more here](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/query-strings-search-params-react-router)